# VGG16 preprocessing dataset generator to dataset mapping

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets, vgg-net

I have a VGG16 model implemented with Keras/tensorflow.

When I call `model.fit`, I pass in a generator of data.  The generator does transforms necessary for a VGGNet:

1. Preprocess the images with [`vgg16.preprocess_input`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input)
2. Convert the label to a one-hot vector via [`to_categorical`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical)

The generator can be seen below and works.  Unfortunately, since there are multiple epochs, I have to set `dataset.repeat(-1)` (infinitely repeat) so the generator doesn't run out.  This in turn requires one to pass a `steps_per_epoch` so a given iteration of training can complete.  As you're probably thinking, this is brittle, (hinges on a known dataset cardinality)!

I have decided it's best to preprocess the training `Dataset` once up front using `Dataset.map`.  However, I am struggling with the construction of a mapping function, it seems `to_categorical` doesn't work with a `tf.Tensor`.  Down below is what I have right now, but I am not sure if there's a latent bug.

**How can I correctly translate the below `Dataset` generator into a `Dataset.map` function?**

---

**Current `Dataset` Generator**

This is implemented (and known to work) with Python 3.8 and `tensorflow==2.4.4`.

```py
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def make_vgg_preprocessing_generator(
    dataset: tf.data.Dataset, num_repeat: int = -1
) -> Iterable[Tuple[tf.Tensor, np.ndarray]]:
    num_classes = len(dataset.class_names)
    for batch_images, batch_labels in dataset.repeat(num_repeat):
        pre_images = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(batch_images)
        pre_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(batch_labels, num_classes)
        yield pre_images, pre_labels


train_ds: tf.data.Dataset  # Not provided in this sample
model.fit(
    make_vgg_preprocessing_generator(train_ds)
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=10,  # Required since default num_repeat is indefinitely
)
```

---

**`Dataset.map` Function**

Here is my current translation that I would like to improve.

```py
def vgg_preprocess_dataset(dataset: tf.data.Dataset) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    num_classes = len(dataset.class_names)

    def _preprocess(x: tf.Tensor, y: tf.Tensor) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
        pre_x = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)
        pre_y = tf.one_hot(y, depth=num_classes)
        return pre_x, pre_y

    return dataset.map(_preprocess)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track! You'll want to replace `to_categorical` with `tf.one_hot`, just as you have, as `tf.one_hot` is specifically for tensors, and is designed for this context. Next, you might want to play around with some of the other `tf.data.Dataset` methods [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) and add them to your pipeline. Right now, your batch size will be one sample, and un-shuffled. An example of some other processing you might do:

```py
def vgg_preprocess_dataset(dataset: tf.data.Dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle_buffer=1000) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    num_classes = len(dataset.class_names)

    def _preprocess(x: tf.Tensor, y: tf.Tensor):
        pre_x = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(x)
        pre_y = tf.one_hot(y, depth=num_classes)
        # pre_y = to_categorical(y, num_classes)
        return pre_x, pre_y

    # bigger buffer is better but slower
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer) 

    # do your mapping after shuffle
    dataset = dataset.map(_preprocess)

    # next batch it
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    
    # this allows your CPU to fetch the next batch (do the above shuffling, mapping, etc) during the 
    # current GPU pass, so that the GPU has minimal downtime
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)

    return dataset

ds = vgg_preprocess_dataset(ds)

# and you just pass it right to fit!
model.fit(ds)
```

Comment: Thank you @tripp, I appreciate the extra information in your response!  I didn't know about `dataset.prefetch`, do you know about `tf.data.AUTOTUNE` (dynamically tuned prefetch buffer size)?  Anyways, thank you again